DataDog Monitor with two queries. How to get values of those two queries each in the notification
Lets say I have a monitor created with two search queries. 1 return how many count and other one totally different query with different groupings and it returns another count.
The notification needs to have both the values of Query A and Query B value. How to get this.
In case of single query it prints value if its used {{value}}.
How to get both these values separately. Tried using A.value and Query_A.value nothing works.
Any help much appreciated.
Tried using A.value and Query_A.value nothing works.

Can you provide more information, e.g. what type of monitor? Are you using a composite monitor?
